# How to use JAXB to generate a xml from a bean

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I wamt to generate xml from  java class using JAXB from a bean class,please let me know which are different approaches for the same.
  I have tried one from vogella website,but i want to know more about the other apporaches and where can i find JAXB API's?

Thanks

Comment: Lots of tutorials on Google, from oracle here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html and java.net here http://jaxb.java.net/guide/

Comment: I wanted few of the sample applications also for the same,i have already gone through these.

Comment: Your question is overly broad. If you have a specific case that you need help with, post your code and point out where you need help. Otherwise, you're not likely to get much in the way of answers.

Comment: I am not able to find specific examples for JAXB ,the one i found was from vogellae website ,i need few more approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JAXB APIs are included in Java SE 6 as well as an implementation.  Other implementations are available:  MOXy, Metro, JaxMe and can be downloaded separately

The following example will help get you going:

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/GettingStarted/TheBasics

I'm the EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) lead and a member of the JAXB 2 (JSR-222) expert group.  My blog contains many examples demonstrating different aspects of JAXB.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com